# Conjugation of homogeneous spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, algebraic-groups, homogeneous-spaces, fundamental-group

Let $X$ be a smooth irreducible algebraic variety
over the field of complex numbers ${\mathbb{C}}$.
Let $x\in X({\mathbb{C}})$.
Let $\tau$ be an automorphism of ${\mathbb{C}}$ (not necessarily continuous),
and  let $\tau X$ denote the $\tau$-conjugated ${\mathbb{C}}$-variety obtained from $X$ by transport of structure
(i.e. by action of $\tau$ on the coefficients of equations defining $X$).
We consider the *topological* fundamental groups $\pi_1(X({\mathbb{C}}),x)$ and $\pi_1((\tau X)({\mathbb{C}}),\tau x)$.

In the papers of Serre,   Exemples de variétés projectives conjuguées non homéomorphes,
C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris **258** (1964), 4194–4196,
 and of Milne and Suh,
[Nonhomeomorphic conjugates of connected Shimura varieties](http://arxiv.org/abs/0804.1953),
 one can find examples of $X$ and $\tau$ such that
$\pi_1((\tau X)({\mathbb{C}}),\tau x)$ and $\pi_1(X({\mathbb{C}}),x)$ are *not* isomorphic.
The authors conclude that in these cases the topological spaces $(\tau X)({\mathbb{C}})$ and $X({\mathbb{C}})$ are not homeomorphic.

In my very recent [preprint with Cyril Demarche](http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.1046)
(excuse me for advertising my own work!) we consider the following situation.
Let $X=G/H$, where $G$ is a connected linear algebraic group over ${\mathbb{C}}$,
and $H\subset G$ any algebraic subgroup, *not necessarily connected*.
Set $x:=eH\in X({\mathbb{C}})$.
We prove that in this case $\pi_1((\tau X)({\mathbb{C}}),\tau x)$ and $\pi_1(X({\mathbb{C}}),x)$ are canonically isomorphic.
I am trying to understand, what this really means.

> **Question.** For  a homogeneous space $X=G/H$ over ${\mathbb{C}}$ as above, and for  $\tau\in {\rm Aut}({\mathbb{C}})$,
>   is it  always true that
>   (1) $(\tau X)({\mathbb{C}})$ and $X(\mathbb{C})$ are homotopically equivalent, or even
>   (2) $(\tau X)({\mathbb{C}})$ and $X(\mathbb{C})$ are homeomorphic, or even
>   (3) $\tau X$ and $X$ are isomorphic ${\mathbb{C}}$-varieties?

Comment: Have you got in mind examples of $X$ not isomorphic to $\tau X$ as homogeneous spaces? I think that we can find $G$ unipotent and not isomorphic to $\tau G$ but this is far to any negative answer to your questions. 

Comment: @Yves: I wanted to know, whether our result that the fundamental groups are isomorphic is trivial because $\tau X$ and $X$ are isomorphic $\mathbb{C}$-varieties.

Comment: What is known when $H=1$?

Comment: What is known when $X$ is connected? What is known when $X$ is finite?

Answer (score 2):

The result in my preprint mentioned in the question was erroneous (the mistake was noticed by a referee). It is possible to construct a quotient  $X=G/H$ and and automorphism $\tau$ of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\pi_1(\tau X(\mathbb{C}))$ is *not isomorphic to* $\pi_1(X(\mathbb{C}))$, see [my preprint with Yves Cornulier](http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.02323) based on his answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199410/conjugation-of-group-extensions). In our example  $G={\rm SL}(n,\mathbb{C})\times \mathbb{C}^*$ with $n\ge 5$, and $H$ is a finite nonabelian subgroup of order 55.
This time the referee noticed no mistakes... Thus the answer to the questions (1), (2), and (3) is NO.

Answer (score 1):

I answer the question in the comment of Tom Goodwillie: What is known when $H=1$?

> **Theorem.** Let $G$ be a connected linear algebraic group over ${\mathbb{C}}$.
> Let $\tau$ be an automorphism of ${\mathbb{C}}$. Then the complex varieties $G$ and $\tau G$ are isomorphic.

Note that I do not claim that the *algebraic groups* $G$ and $\tau G$ are always isomorphic, see the comment of Yves Cornulier.

*Proof.* It suffices to show that *as a variety* $G$ can be defined over $\mathbb Q$.

Write $G^{\rm u}$ for the unipotent radical of $G$, and set $G^{\rm red}:=G/G^{\rm u}$,
then $G^{\rm red}$ is a connected reductive ${\mathbb{C}}$-group.
By Mostow's theorem $G\simeq G^{\rm u}\rtimes G^{\rm red}$, hence $G\simeq G^{\rm u}\times G^{\rm red}$ as a ${\mathbb{C}}$-variety.
Using the exponential map, one sees easily that $G^{\rm u}$ is isomorphic to an affine space (the Lie algebra of $G^{\rm u}$) as a variety,
hence *as a variety* it can be defined over ${\mathbb{Q}}$.
Now it suffices to show that the reductive ${\mathbb{C}}$-group  $G^{\rm red}$ admits a ${\mathbb{Q}}$-form (as an algebraic group).

Set $G^{\rm ss}=[G,G]$, it is a connected semisimple group.
Let $G^{\rm sc}$ denote the universal covering of $G^{\rm ss}$,
it is a simply connected semisimple $\mathbb{C}$-group.
Let $Z^0$ denote the identity component of the center $Z$ of $G^{\rm red}$, it is a $\mathbb{C}$-torus.
We have a canonical epimorphism $\phi\colon G^{\rm sc}\times_{\mathbb{C}} Z^0\to G$ with finite central kernel $\mu$.

Let $G_{1,{\mathbb{Q}}}$ be the direct product over ${\mathbb{Q}}$ of a split ${\mathbb{Q}}$-form (Chevalley's form)
of $G^{\rm sc}$ and a split ${\mathbb{Q}}$-form of the torus $Z^0$.
We have an epimorphism $\phi\colon G_{1,{\mathbb{C}}}\to G^{\rm red}$.
Since $\mu\subset T_{1,{\mathbb{C}}}$ for some *split* maximal torus $T_{1,{\mathbb{Q}}}\subset G_{1,{\mathbb{Q}}}$,
we see that $\mu$ is defined over ${\mathbb{Q}}$ in $T_{1,{\mathbb{C}}}$,
i.e. $\mu=\mu_{\mathbb{Q}}\times_{\mathbb{Q}} {\mathbb{C}}$ for some central ${\mathbb{Q}}$-subgroup $\mu_{\mathbb{Q}}\subset G_{1,{\mathbb{Q}}}$.

Now we set $G_{\mathbb Q}^{\rm red}$ to be  $G_{1,{\mathbb{Q}}}/\mu_{\mathbb{Q}}$,
it is a ${\mathbb{Q}}$-form of $G^{\rm red}$.